# Thymeleaf/Webflow SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments

Tags: el, spring-webflow

Can anyone provide a hint about what I should be looking for here in order to debug? The error provides few comprehensible pointers (for me).

I am almost certain the error is my flow.xml on-entry.

NOTE: This occurs at the entry to one webflow. All other webflows work fine.

```html
<on-start>
   <evaluate expression="testTypeViewService.getVwNewTestType(requestParameters.businessId,false)" result="flowScope.vwNewTestType" />
   <evaluate expression="testTypeViewService.generateTutMap(flowRequestContext,flowScope.vwNewTestType)"
   result="flowScope.vwNewTestType" />
   <evaluate expression="testTypeViewService.generateTtMap(flowRequestContext,flowScope.vwNewTestType, 2)"
   result="flowScope.vwNewTestType" />
  
</on-start>
```

The key point in the log file seems to be this:

> [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,622: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1198) Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {exception=org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments}
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.raiseInternalException(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:976)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.consumeArguments(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.maybeEatMethodArgs(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:443)

Fuller log  data is as follows:

> [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,567: org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:150) Looking up JNDI object with name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomai
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,569: org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource.getProperty(JndiPropertySource.java:90) JNDI lookup for name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].. Returning null.
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,575: org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:81) Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemProperties]
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,578: org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:81) Searching for key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in [systemEnvironment]
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,582: org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:103) Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source. Returning [null]
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,604: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [[FlowHandlerMapping.DefaultFlowHandler@76eba396]]: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,605: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [[FlowHandlerMapping.DefaultFlowHandler@76eba396]]: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,606: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [[FlowHandlerMapping.DefaultFlowHandler@76eba396]]: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,609: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [[FlowHandlerMapping.DefaultFlowHandler@76eba396]]: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,610: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:134) Resolving exception from handler [[FlowHandlerMapping.DefaultFlowHandler@76eba396]]: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,613: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.determineViewName(SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.java:219) Resolving to default view 'error' for exception of type [org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException]
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,615: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.getModelAndView(SimpleMappingExceptionResolver.java:341) Exposing Exception as model attribute 'exception'
>   [DEBUG] 2015-09-10 11:02:21,622: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1198) Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {exception=org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments}
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1051E:(pos 34): Unexpected ran out of arguments
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.raiseInternalException(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:976)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.consumeArguments(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:476)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.maybeEatMethodArgs(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:443)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.maybeEatMethodOrProperty(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:738)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatDottedNode(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:397)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.maybeEatNode(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:360)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatPrimaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:345)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatUnaryExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:337)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatPowerIncDecExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:293)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatProductExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:272)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatSumExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:255)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatRelationalExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:210)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatLogicalAndExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatLogicalOrExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:186)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.eatExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:146)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:32)
>       at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:76)
>       at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpressionParser.parseSpelExpression(SpringELExpressionParser.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpressionParser.parseExpression(SpringELExpressionParser.java:77)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.parseEvaluateAction(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:870)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.parseActions(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:845)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.parseTransition(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:817)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.parseTransitions(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:802)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.parseAndAddViewState(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:555)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.buildStates(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:214)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.FlowAssembler.directAssembly(FlowAssembler.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.FlowAssembler.assembleFlow(FlowAssembler.java:91)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.DefaultFlowHolder.assembleFlow(DefaultFlowHolder.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.DefaultFlowHolder.getFlowDefinition(DefaultFlowHolder.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.getFlowDefinition(FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.java:60)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:138)
>       at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:238)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, this was a basic error. I assumed it was on-entry. I was wrong.

Webflow parses the entire xml file on entry. My error was further down where I was missing a closing bracket for a requestparameter argument (after "businessId"):

```html
<transition on="doedittesttype" to="restart">
  <evaluate
    expression="testTypeViewService.updateTestType(vwNewTestType, sessionParameters.businessId"
    result="flowScope.vwNewTestType" />    
  </transition>
```